# How to select subjects with specific properties from RDF with Jena?

Tags: java, rdf, jena

This is a follow up question on my last one, since I am still struggling with this topic... I need to select some subjects from my model that meet specific requirements..

If I list my statements (this is only short part of the output), I get something like this:

```
WorkOrder2 hasType Workorder .
WorkOrder2 hasResult Fuselage22 .
WorkOrder2 type NamedIndividual .
```

Now, I would like to select and iterate thourgh all subjects that `hasType Workorder`. My idea was something like this:

```
public static ArrayList<String> listAllWorkorders(Model model) {
        ArrayList<String> workorders = new ArrayList<String>();

        // list of all work orders associated with given fuselage and work
        // station
        ResIterator it = model.listSubjectsWithProperty(
                ResourceFactory.createProperty(ArumCorePrefix + "hasType"), ArumCorePrefix + "Workorder");
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Resource r = it.next();
            String workorder = trimPrefix(r.toString());

            workorders.add(workorder);

        }

        // sort the result alphabetically
        Collections.sort(workorders);

        return workorders;
    }
```

However, it does not return anything... If I use `listSubjectsWithProperty` without the second argument (String), it works but returns not only Workorders but some toher stuff with `hasType` property, which I do not want to. What is wrong with my code! Can I use something like this and make it work?
Dont worry about the `static` use of this function (I will take care of this non-elegant way as soon as I udnerstand whats wrong.)

Also, I would like to implement some more compelx filtering - for example selecting subjects with multiple properties that all has to match in order to return them, like `hasType Workorder, hasResult someResult, inStation station` etc... Does Jena support something like this! If not, what is the common approach?

Thanks for any tips!

And a follow-up: How do I check whether some statement is present in my model? I know that there is `model.contains(Statements s)` method but do I have to create the statement in argument in roder to call this method? Isnt there some more elegant way like `model.contains(Resource r, Property p, Resource o)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can do this in Jena, but they mostly come down to calling

- [StmtIterator Model.listStatements(Resource,Property,RDFNode)](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html#listStatements%28com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource,%20com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property,%20com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode%29)

with the resource as the first argument, and `null` as the second and third arguments, as a wildcard.  The other methods that do similar things are really just special cases of this.  For instance,

- `listObjectsOfProperty(Property p)` — `listStatements(null,p,null)` and take the object from each statement.
- `listObjectsOfProperty(Resource s, Property p)` — `listStatements(s,p,null)` and take the object from each statement.
- `listResourcesWithProperty(Property p)` — `listStatements(null,p,null)` and take the subject from each statement
- `listResourcesWithProperty(Property p, RDFNode o)` — `listStatements(null,p,o)` and take the subject from each statement

For convenience, you might prefer to use the method

- [StmtIterator Resource.listProperties()](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Resource.html#listProperties%28com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property%29)

which returns an iterator over all the statements in the resource's model with the given resource as a subject.

Here's some example code that includes your model and uses each of these methods:

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.StmtIterator;

public class ResourcePropertiesExample {
    final static String NS = "http://example.org/";
    final static String modelText = "" +
            "@prefix : <"+NS+"> .\n" +
            ":WorkOrder2 :hasType :Workorder .\n" +
            ":WorkOrder2 :hasResult :Fuselage22 .\n" +
            ":WorkOrder2 :type :NamedIndividual .\n" +
            "";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        model.read( new ByteArrayInputStream( modelText.getBytes()), null, "TTL" );
        final Resource workOrder2 = model.getResource( NS+"WorkOrder2" );

        System.out.println( "Using Model.listStatements()" );
        StmtIterator stmts = model.listStatements( workOrder2, null, (RDFNode) null );
        while ( stmts.hasNext() ) {
            System.out.println( stmts.next() );
        }

        System.out.println( "Using Resource.listProperties()" );
        stmts = workOrder2.listProperties();
        while ( stmts.hasNext() ) {
            System.out.println( stmts.next() );
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Using Model.listStatements()
[http://example.org/WorkOrder2, http://example.org/type, http://example.org/NamedIndividual]
[http://example.org/WorkOrder2, http://example.org/hasResult, http://example.org/Fuselage22]
[http://example.org/WorkOrder2, http://example.org/hasType, http://example.org/Workorder]
Using Resource.listProperties()
[http://example.org/WorkOrder2, http://example.org/type, http://example.org/NamedIndividual]
[http://example.org/WorkOrder2, http://example.org/hasResult, http://example.org/Fuselage22]
[http://example.org/WorkOrder2, http://example.org/hasType, http://example.org/Workorder]
```

As for checking whether a model contains certain statements, you can, as you noted, use Model.contains, and I don't think there's anything the matter with that.  You can also use the various Resource `has*` methods, such as

- hasLiteral( Property p, [various types of literal] )
- hasProperty( Property p, RDFNode / String / String, String )

Using these, you could use, continuing the example above, and assuming you'd defined the property `hasResult` and resources `fuselage21` and `fuselage22`:

```java
workOrder2.hasProperty( hasResult, fuselage21 ); // false
workOrder2.hasProperty( hasResult, fuselage22 ); // true
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still have a problem: when I call model.contains(wororder, hasResult, NS + "fuselage22");, it says false and I dont know why.. the resource.has(Property p) doesnt work either, even though that the satetements are obvisouly there...

Comment: There's a difference between `NS+"fuselage22"`, which is a string, and `model.getResource(NS+"fuselage22")` which creates a Resource.  The statements that the model contains (in this case) have _resources_ as their objects, not strings.  That's why I did, for instance, `final Resource workOrder2 = model.getResource( NS+"WorkOrder2" );`.  You need to do `final Resource fuselage22 = model.getResource(NS+"fuselage22");`.